# "Es ist zu beobachten" als Passiv

Tags: grammar, passive

Betrachten wir folgenden Satz:

> Es ist zu beobachten, dass der pH-Wert steigt.

So etwas könnte in einem wissenschaftlichen Paper stehen. Wenn es auf Englisch verfasst wird, dann schreibt der Autor möglicherweise:

> It is observed that the pH value increases.

Im Englischen verwendet man also direkt ein Passiv, und semantisch ist der deutsche Satz ja nichts anderes. Aber statt eines Passivs mit „sein“ oder „werden“ wird eine Konstruktion verwendet, die ich allenfalls als Partizip der Notwendigkeit identifizieren könnte – doch es wird ja ein bereits stattfindender/stattgefundener Prozess beschrieben.

**Fragen:**

1. Hat diese Passivkonstruktion einen Namen?
2. Wie produktiv ist sie? Auf Anhieb sind mir nur Verben der Wahrnehmung, wie „sehen“ oder „erkennen“, in dieser Konstruktion geläufig. Oder ist es nur eine beschränkte Sonderheit?
3. Was drückt die Konstruktion aus? Eventuell eine Aspektunterscheidung?

Comment: Ist "Es wird ein Anstieg des pH-Wertes beobachtet" oder "Es wird ein pH-Wert-Anstieg beobachtet" nicht eine passende Übersetzung im Vorgangspassiv?

Comment: Für mich wäre "Es ist zu beobachten" eher so was wie "It can be observed". Wie @JaschaGoltermann bereits hingewiesen hat, lässt sich die grammatikalische Struktur 1:1 übertragen.

Comment: Im Deutschen kann man dies durchaus mit anderen Verben auch machen, beispielsweise *Es ist anzumerken, dass...* oder *Es ist festzustellen, dass...*. Diese Struktur kann dann auch in's Englische übertragen werden als *It is to be noted* oder *It is to be noticed*. Ich würde die *It is (to be) ...*-Konstruktion übrigens übersetzen als *Man kann ...*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Es ist zu beobachten* hat zwei Bedeutungen:

Die eines echten Passivs für einen Satz, der Verpflichtung ausdrückt:

> Die Steuererklärung ist bis zum 31. Mai abzugeben.

Das Gegenüber im Aktiv wird mit "haben zu" abgebildet:

> Sie haben die Steuererklärung bis zum 31. Mai abzugeben.

Die Passivvariante ist verbreitet in Behördendeutsch, da ein Subjekt bei allgemeinen Anordnungen meist irrelevant ist. In der direkten Ansprache wäre das jedoch *extrem* unhöflich.

In der gleichen Konstruktion dient das Verb als Prädikatsausdruck der dem Subjekt eine Eigenschaft gibt:

> Die Musik ist zu hören. (Die Musik kann gehört werden/ist hörbar)
>   Sie hat viel zu erzählen. (Sie kann viel erzählen)

Zifonun bezeichnet es als "modale Verwendung von haben/sein", andere Autoren ebenfalls. Ich finde diese Bezeichnung unbefriedigend.
Beides ist als produktiv einzustufen.

Answer (score 1):

Der deutsche Satz, der semantisch und grammatisch dem englischen Satz

> It is observed that the pH value increases.

am nächsten kommt, ist

> Es wird beobachtet, dass der pH-Wert steigt.

Der Satz bringt zum Ausdruck, dass tatsächlich eine Beobachtung stattfindet. Es gibt also ganz sicher jemanden, der den ph-Wert über eine gewisse Zeit hinweg beobachtet und dabei eine Veränderung nach oben feststellt. Hier liegt weder eine Möglichkeit noch ein Angebot vor.

---

In dem Satz

> Man kann beobachten, dass der pH-Wert steigt.

wird zwar ebenfalls ausgedrückt, dass der pH-Wert steigt, aber die Beobachtung wird nur als Möglichkeit geschildert: Falls es einen Beobachter gibt, wird dieser den Anstieg bemerken. Aber es ist keineswegs gewiss, dass dieser Beobachter existiert. Der pH-Wert könnte auch völlig unbeobachtet ansteigen.

Dieser Satz stellt ein Angebot an den dar, der den Satz liest oder hört: Dem Empfänger der Botschaft wird angeboten, das Steigen des pH-Wertes zu beobachten.

---

Kommen wir nun zu dem Satz, um den es in der Frage geht:

> Es ist zu beobachten, dass der pH-Wert steigt.

Hierbei handelt es sich um eine Passivumschreibung mit einer Form von »*sein*« (»ist«) und einem Infinitiv (»beobachten«) mit »*zu*«. Diese Konstruktion ersetzt einen Passivsatz mit den Modalfaktoren »müssen«, »sollen« oder »können«.

> <sub>Passivsatz:</sub>
>   Das Auto **muss** gewaschen werden.
>   <sub>Passivumschreibung:</sub>
>   Das Auto ist zu waschen.
>
> <sub>Passivsatz:</sub>
>   Der Zaun **soll** gestrichen werden.
>   <sub>Passivumschreibung:</sub>
>   Der Zaun ist zu streichen.
>
> <sub>Passivsatz:</sub>
>   Der Schmutzfleck **kann** gesehen werden.
>   <sub>Passivumschreibung:</sub>
>   Der Schmutzfleck ist zu sehen.

Es handelt sich also um eine Aufforderung (*muss*, *soll*) oder um das Anbieten einer Möglichkeit (*kann*), wobei Letzteres auch als das simple Vorliegen einer Möglichkeit interpretiert werden kann. Jedoch hat die Passivumschreibung den Nachteil, dass man ihr nicht mehr ansieht, ob sie als »*muss*«, »*soll*« oder »*kann*« zu interpretieren ist.

---

Die Verben der Wahrnehmung und die Verben, die eine Erwartung ausdrücken (»*annehmen*«, »*erwarten*«, »*hoffen*«, »*befürchten*« usw.), haben gemeinsam, dass sie an ein Ereignis geknüpft werden können, das beobachtet oder erwartet wird, und dieses Ereignis findet dann häufig in einem Relativsatz platz, der mit »*dass*« eingeleitet wird:

> Es ist zu hoffen, dass die Vorräte ausreichen.
>   Man kann (nur) hoffen, dass die Vorräte ausreichen.
>
> Es ist zu befürchten, dass unser Kunde nicht zahlen kann.
>   Man muss befürchten, dass unser Kunde nicht zahlen kann.
>
> Es ist zu hören, dass hier ein Kind spricht.
>   Man kann hören, dass hier ein Kind spricht.
>
> **Es ist zu beobachten, dass der pH-Wert steigt.**
>   Man kann beobachten, dass der pH-Wert steigt.

Im ursprünglichen Sinn handelt es sich bei dieser Formulierung also um eine Aufforderung oder um ein Angebot. Dem Empfänger der Botschaft wird angeboten, das Ereignis zu beobachten. Jedoch wird das Angebot (also die »kann«-Variante) gerade im Fall der Wahrnehmung-Verben meist als das Vorliegen einer Möglichkeit (ohne Aufforderungs-Charakter) interpretiert.